# Convert two dimensional array to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
$data=array(
   array('id'=>12,'name'=>'box1','color'=>'red','content_id'=>18,'content'=>'roses'),
   array('id'=>12,'name'=>'box1','color'=>'red','content_id'=>22,'content'=>'daisies'),
   array('id'=>38,'name'=>'box2','color'=>'green','content_id'=>22,'content'=>'daisies'),

);
```

And I want to convert it using this structure:

```
  $structure = array('id'=>
    array('name','color','content_id'=>array(
      'content')));
```

So it becomes:

```
array(
  '12'=>array('name'=>'box1','color'=>'red','content_id'=>array(
     '18'=>'roses',
     '22'=>'daisies')),
   '38'=>array('name'=>'box2','color'=>'green','content_id'=>array(
     '22'=>'daisies'))
);
```

I created a function that works for a single $data array (i.e. x_array($data[0],$structure)):

```
    function x_array($data,$struc,$first=true)
    {
        foreach ($struc as $struc_field=>$inner_struc)
        {
            if (!is_array($inner_struc))
                {$result[$inner_struc]=$data[$inner_struc];}
            else {
                $res=x_array($data,$inner_struc,false);

                //ignore the first field name and use it's value as key instead
                if ($first) {$result[$data[$struc_field]]=$res;}
                else {$result[$struc_field][$data[$struc_field]]=$res;}

                }

        }
        return $result;

    }
```

check it at: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y3e-wxh

However I'm stuck on what to do next, when it comes to integrate the information of more than one array without duplicating or overwriting information. Note that I posted a simplified data and structure array, the final function should be able to manage any structure deep and any number/name of fields.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$data=array(
   array('id'=>12,'name'=>'box1','color'=>'red','content_id'=>18,'content'=>'roses'),
   array('id'=>12,'name'=>'box1','color'=>'red','content_id'=>22,'content'=>'daisies'),
   array('id'=>38,'name'=>'box2','color'=>'green','content_id'=>22,'content'=>'daisies'),

);

$res = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
   $res[$val['id']]['name']          = $val['name'];
   $res[$val['id']]['color']         = $val['color'];
   $res[$val['id']]['content_id'][$val['content_id']]  = $val['content'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [name] => box1
            [color] => red
            [content_id] => Array
                (
                    [18] => roses
                    [22] => daisies
                )

        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [name] => box2
            [color] => green
            [content_id] => Array
                (
                    [22] => daisies
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that would probably work, but, as I said, I'm trying to do a universal function rather than an array-structure specific one